# "The global element ... has already been declared" errors

Tags: c#, wcf

I've just taken over the running of a project with some WCF service references, and I've noticed there are a bunch of warnings about one of the generated XSD files along the lines of:

> The global attribute 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/:FactoryType' has already been declared.
>
> The global element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/:anyType' has already been declared.
>
> The global element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/:boolean' has already been declared.

I can't seem to see why these errors are happening; it doesn't look like it is referenced multiple times.  If I update the service reference, or delete and re-add it, I get the same errors again.  How can I diagnose and fix these warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error seems to be inherent to the Visual Studio "Enable XSD as type definition language" option in the "WCF Options" tab for a project.  I tried creating a new project with that enabled, and adding my 2 service references, and I got the same set of warnings again.  The solution for me was to just turn off that XSD code generation option.